# Spring-Boot: Can not Create Custom Security Expression

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring boot 2.4.1 and am following the instructions from [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) to create a Custom Security Expression. Unfortunately, I can't createSecurityExpressionRoot method and my annotation also doesn't work.

I get an error when calling into api

```
[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasAccessToCollection('Administrator')'] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method hasAccessToCollection(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot
```

My Service

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAccessToCollection('Administrator')")
    public Map getCustomPermission() {
        Map<String, String> response  = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("message", "Successful");
        }};
        return response;
    }
```

My CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot 
        extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    
    public IcodeMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }
    
    public boolean hasAccessToCollection(String permission) {
        return true;
    }
    
    public boolean hasAccessToCollection(String permission, String attribute) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

My CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler  {
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = 
      new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(
      Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = 
          new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
        root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ditch the handler and the root. Just write a regular bean class with the 2 methods you need an write `@yourBean.hasAccessToCollection('Administrator')`. This is the preferred way to write your own security expressions.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've used `@CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot .hasAccessToCollection('Administrator')`. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Which is the wrong bean name. Bean names start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your MethodSecurityConfig this:

```
@Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
       
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();

        var expresionAdvice= new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        expresionAdvice.setExpressionHandler(getExpressionHandler());

        decisionVoters.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expresionAdvice));
        decisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter()); //It is necessary to add this one when we override the default AccessDecisionManager
        /*Block N°3  Add the customized RoleVoter Bean if you have one
          decisionVoters.add(roleVoter);
          */
       return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }
```

https://medium.com/@islamboulila/how-to-create-a-custom-security-expression-method-in-spring-security-e5b6353f062f